# issue with dafault value of argparse

Tags: python, default, argparse

I'm working with argparse and I want you to ask a question. Can I use an value default value when the user doesn't input it in terminal? I know that I can do it with for example statement if "something" and do it mechanically. But is it faster and more efficient way?
Example of code:

```
import sys
import argparse
import csv

def read_from_csv(path):
    words = []
    with open(path, "r") as file_handle:
        reader = csv.reader(file_handle)
        for row in reader:
            words.append(row)
    return words

def creating_a_password(list_of_words):
    new_list  = []
    for j in range(list_of_words):
        


def main(argument):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--posible-seprators")
    parser.add_argument("--padding-digits")
    parser.add_argument("--padding-symbols-number")
    parser.add_argument("--possible-padding-symbols")
    parser.add_argument("--words-number")
    parser.add_argument("--minimal-word-length")
    parser.add_argument("--maximal-word-length")
    parser.add_argument("--generated-passwords")
    a = read_from_csv("data.txt")
    args = parser.parse_args(argument[1:])
    b = creating_a_password(a,args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: `add_argument()` accepts a `default` parameter that you can set to whatever you like. the argparse docs explain this in detail: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default

Comment: Add a `print(args)` debugging line to your code.  When working with `argparse` and its results, efficiency and speed is not an issue.  It is run only once.

Comment: The code that should be demonstrating the problem makes no sense. The parameter `list_of_words` sounds like a list, but gets used as an `int`, and the actual parsed arguments are passed as an argument for parameter that is never defined.

Comment: I meant that if user didn't put value argparse will get for example 3. If user put it, it will get users value.